# Get results from search engine

Tags: python

The search engine in particular is search.lycos.co.uk. I can search it through the script but i can't grab each individual result from the source, any help is greatly appreciated.
Edit:

```
host = 'http://search.lycos.co.uk/?query=%s&page2=%s' % (str(query), repr(page))
req = urllib2.Request(host)
req.add_header('User-Agent', User_Agent)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
source = response.read()
```

Not sure where to go from here to get  each result.

Comment: More details, please. Code samples, etc.

Comment: Can you please show the script?

Comment: Is there an actual programming API from the search engine rather than trying to parse/read pages written for human end users?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
query='testing!'
page=1
host = 'http://search.lycos.co.uk/?query=%s&page2=%s' % (str(query), repr(page))
print urllib2.urlopen(host).read()
```

Try it there and see if it works. It works here.

Also, I created the urllib2.Request and it worked here:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

data = {'query': 'testing', 'page2': '1'}
req = urllib2.Request(host, data=urllib.urlencode(data))
req.add_header('User-Agent', <yours>)
print urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

**Following-up**, those are good modules if you want to scrape the data:

- [lxml](http://lxml.de/)
- [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: Sorry you may have misunderstood, i can do that part but i need to get each result seperately from the source which i am unsure how to go about

Comment: So, it's an other kind of problem... Take a look at lxml or BeautifulSoup. I took a look at the response and there's a pretty straightforward way to extract the results. Maybe you should edit your question a little bit. Cheers!

Comment: sorry, i read the question there and i wasn't clear at all, i will look into them, new thing for me so having some difficulty getting it right

Answer (score 0):

Lycos encrypted their search result. But, you can try Google.

```
import urllib, urllib2
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from time import sleep
from random import choice, random

def scrapping_google(query):
    g_url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=%s&num=100&hl=en&start=0"  %(urllib.quote_plus(query))
    request = urllib2.Request(g_url, None, {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0'})
    open_url = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    read_url = open_url.read()
    g_soup = BeautifulSoup(read_url)

    remove_tag = re.compile(r'<.*?>')

    g_dict = {}

    scrap_count = g_soup.find('div', attrs={'id' : 'resultStats'})
    count = remove_tag.sub('', str(scrap_count)).replace('.','')
    only_count = count[0:-16]
    print 'Prediction result: ', only_count
    print '\n'

    for li in g_soup.findAll('li', attrs={'class' : 'g'}):
        links = li.find('a')
        print links['href']
        scrap_content = li.find('span', attrs={'class' : 'st'})
        content = remove_tag.sub('', str(scrap_content)).replace('.','')
        print content

    return g_dict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fetch_links = scrapping_google('jokowi')
```